# Using find('list') in Cakephp 1.3 with custom fields

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm working in a cakephp 1.3 project. I have a problem retrieving some data from my database using find('list'). Before my last change I had this code:

```
$listaHabilidades = $this->Habilidad->find('list',array('fields'=>array('id','habilidad'),'order'=>array('habilidad'))));
```

This command gives me the next array:

```
Array
(
    [40] =>  Bicicleta
    [42] =>  enganches de poleas
    [28] =>  Escalada
    [43] =>  transfer
    [41] => 4x4
    [53] => Administración Linux
    [72] => Ángeles
    [59] => Baile Flamenco
    [57] => Baloncesto
    [39] => Barranquismo
    [66] => Cante Flamenco
    [30] => Conducción
    [52] => Consola Linux
    [80] => cuarta prueba
    [75] => Demonios
    [84] => Esgrima
    [58] => Futbol
    [76] => Limpiar
    [77] => Limpiar2
    [54] => Linux
    [27] => Montañismo
    [60] => MS Office
    [65] => Natación
    [45] => Patinaje
    [56] => PC
    [78] => probar
    [44] => Programación
    [82] => Protocolo
    [81] => quinta prueba
    [63] => Tenis
    [79] => tercera prueba
    [83] => Triatlón
    [55] => W8
    [51] => XP
    [64] => Zapateado
)
```

But I had a problem because the data can have spaces at the begining of the field 'habilidad' and I want to get the data without the and order them also without them. So I changed the command to:

```
$listaHabilidades = $this->Habilidad->find('list',array('fields'=>array('id','trim(Habilidad.habilidad)'),'order'=>array('trim(Habilidad.habilidad)'))));
```

It gives me the next array:

```
Array
(
    [41] => 
    [53] => 
    [72] => 
    [59] => 
    [57] => 
    [39] => 
    [40] => 
    [66] => 
    [30] => 
    [52] => 
    [80] => 
    [75] => 
    [42] => 
    [28] => 
    [84] => 
    [58] => 
    [76] => 
    [77] => 
    [54] => 
    [27] => 
    [60] => 
    [65] => 
    [45] => 
    [56] => 
    [78] => 
    [44] => 
    [82] => 
    [81] => 
    [63] => 
    [79] => 
    [43] => 
    [83] => 
    [55] => 
    [51] => 
    [64] => 
)
```

How can I get the list trimmed (without loops)?

Comment: you can trim a particular field of db table using.
`UPDATE habilidads SET habilidad = TRIM(habilidad)
WHERE 1 = 1;` , you can also do trim from sql final list but this would make more sense if you trim values earlier as it would make a query faster

Comment: I know that but what happens if I want to use any mysql function without modify the stored data? How I have to retrieve the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you add a [virtual field](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#virtualfields) to your model:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    't_habilidad' => 'LTRIM(Habilidad.habilidad)'
);
```

Then use

```
$listaHabilidades = $this->Habilidad->find('list', array('fields'=>array('id','habilidad'), 'order' => array('t_habilidad'))));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure how CakePHP generates the query internally, but you can just trim it in php after retrieval

```
$listaHabilidades = $this->Habilidad->find('list',array('fields'=>array('id','habilidad'),'order'=>array('habilidad'))));
$listaHabilidades = array_map('trim', $listaHabilidades);

// voila
```